# apply function on certain columns in nested variable in r

Tags: r, purrr

I want to apply a vectorised operation on certain columns in the nested variable. The function that I want to apply is to find the sum of missing value in the numeric features i.e. `weight` and `calories`. The data frame that I have is as following

```
df <- data.frame(country = c("US", "US", "UK", "PAK"),name = c("David", 
"James", "Junaid", "Ali"), fruit = c("Apple", "banana", "orange", "melon"), 
weight = c(90,110,120,NA), calories = c(NA,20, NA,NA))

  country   name  fruit weight calories
1      US  David  Apple     90       NA
2      US  James banana    110       20
3      UK Junaid orange    120       NA
4     PAK    Ali  melon     NA       NA
```

When I nest the data frame

```
nested_df <- df %>% group_by(country) %>% nest()


# A tibble: 3 × 2
  country             data
   <fctr>           <list>
1      US <tibble [2 × 4]>
2      UK <tibble [1 × 4]>
3     PAK <tibble [1 × 4]>
```

I have tried to use the following syntax but to no avail.

```
nested_df %>% mutate(missings = map(data, c("weight", "calories")) %>% 
                             map_lgl(function(x) sum(!is.na(x))/length(x) ==1))`
```

The result I am expected are as following

```
`# A tibble: 3 × 3
  country             data missings
   <fctr>           <list>    <lgl>
1      US <tibble [2 × 4]>       FALSE
2      UK <tibble [1 × 4]>       FALSE
3     PAK <tibble [1 × 4]>       TRUE`
```

however, what i am getting is

```
` A tibble: 3 × 3
  country             data missings
   <fctr>           <list>    <lgl>
1      US <tibble [2 × 4]>       NA
2      UK <tibble [1 × 4]>       NA
3     PAK <tibble [1 × 4]>       NA`
```

Answer (score 0):

This will check whether more than 50% of values are `NA`...

```
colstocheck <- c("weight", "calories")
nested_df %>% mutate(missings = (map_lgl(data, 
                function(x) sum(is.na(x[,colstocheck]))/length(x[,colstocheck]) > 0.5)))

# A tibble: 3 x 3
  country             data missings
   <fctr>           <list>    <lgl>
1      US <tibble [2 x 4]>    FALSE
2      UK <tibble [1 x 4]>    FALSE
3     PAK <tibble [1 x 4]>     TRUE
```

Comment: @docendodiscimus I have changed it to `x` to avoid confusion

Comment: hey thanks, but what if I want to check for more than 50% missing value rather than all!!

Comment: @AzamYahya I've amended the solution above